# SAPUI5 with SAP Business One (SQL Server)

Tags: sapui5, sapb1

Is it possible to connect SAP UI5 web application with SAP Business One running in SQL Server with Service Layer (B1 version 10)?

Since most (almost all) of the tutorials/documentations of SAPUI5 are related to SAP S/4 HANA or Business One with HANA (using xsjs / XS engine, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's supported on SQL from V10 (it's actually present in some earlier versions). Obviously you can't use anything Hana related such as calculation views, XS, etc.

"We're pleased that Service Layer service is enabled for Microsoft SQL Server since Version 10 PL01, see SAP Note 2875568."

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of not having Analytical modules in MS SQL service layer. Do we have any sample application or tutorial on "How to connect SAP Ui5 application with SAP Business One service layer of MS SQL?